# How exactly do you prove a union? Example included.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My homework question is:

Let $X$ be a set and $A,B \subseteq X$. Show that $(X \setminus A) \cup (X \setminus B)=X\setminus(A\cap B)$

My answer is:

Consider an arbitrary $x \in (X \setminus A) \cup (X \setminus B)$. Either $x \in (X \setminus A)$ or $x \in (X \setminus B)$. If $x \in (X \setminus A)$, then $x \in X$ but $x \notin A$. By definition, if $x \notin A$ then $x \notin A\cap B$. Hence, $x\in X\setminus(A\cap B)$. If $x \in (X\setminus B)$, then $x \in X$ but $x \notin B$. By definition, if $x \notin B$ then $x \notin A\cap B$ also. As $x \in X\setminus (A \cap B)$, then $(X\setminus A)\cup (X \setminus B) \subseteq X \setminus (A \cap B)$

Consider an arbitrary $x \in X\setminus (A\cap B)$. Consequently, $x \in X$ and $x \notin (A \cap B)$, and therefore, $x \notin A$ and $x \notin B$. Since, $x \in X$, and $A,B \subseteq X$, then $x \in (X \setminus A)$ and $x \in (X \setminus B)$. Finally, $x\in (X\setminus A)\cup (X\setminus B)$. Hence, $X\setminus (A\cap B)\subseteq (X\setminus A)\cup (X\setminus B)$ Q.E.D

After writing this down I started to think that how I proved $x\in (X\setminus A)\cup (X\setminus B)$ was wrong as I proved both $x \in (X\setminus A)$ and $x \in (X\setminus B)$. If I remember correctly this proves an intersection instead. Is this proof right or did I make a mistake and how do I fix it?

Comment: Union is "at least one". You're fine.

Comment: YOur error is "and x∉(A∩B), and therefore, x∉A and x∉B"  If $x \not \in$ BOTH $A$ and $B$ then it is either not in $A$, or not in $B$ or not in either.  But it *could* be in one and not they other. So you *didn't* prove $x$ in *BOTH* $X\setminus A$ and $X\setminus B$ (and therefore in the *intersection*). What you did (n't quite but tried to) argue was that $x \in X\setminus A$ ***OR*** $x\in X\setminus B$.  And *that* would mean it is in the *union*.

Comment: @SeanRoberson No, he/she isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *did* have an error and you did (incorrectly) argue that $x$ is in the *intersection*.

You argued:

> Consider an arbitrary x∈X∖(A∩B). Consequently, x∈X **and x∉(A∩B), and therefore, x∉A and x∉B**. Since, x∈X, and A,B⊆X, then x∈(X∖A) **and** x∈(X∖B). Finally, x∈(X∖A)∪(X∖B). Hence, X∖(A∩B)⊆(X∖A)∪(X∖B) Q.E.D$

Now $x \not \in (A\cap B)$ meaning that [$x \in A$ and $x\in B$] is false.... means that  [$x \in A$] and [$x\in B$] are not **BOTH** true.  But that doesn't mean they are both *false*.  It means one or the other (and maybe, but not necessarily, both) are false.

In short if $x \not \in (A\cap B)$ the *either* $x \not \in A$ ***OR*** (not "and") $x \not \in B$.

So you would argue as $A,B\subset X$ then $x \in (X\setminus A)$ ***OR*** (not "and") $x \in (X\setminus B)$.

ANd *that* is how you argue a *union*; by showing $x$ is in one *or* the other.

So $x \in (X\setminus A)\cup (X\setminus B)$.

In other words:

> Consider an arbitrary x∈X∖(A∩B). Consequently, x∈X and x∉(A∩B), and therefore, x∉A **OR** x∉B. Since, x∈X, and A,B⊆X, then x∈(X∖A) **OR** x∈(X∖B). Finally, x∈(X∖A)∪(X∖B). Hence, X∖(A∩B)⊆(X∖A)∪(X∖B) Q.E.D$

Answer (score 0):

Here it is another way to approach it for the sake of curiosity.

According to the corresponding properties of the set operations, we have that

\begin{align*}
(X\backslash A)\cup(X\backslash B) & = (X\cap A^{c})\cup(X\cap B^{c})\\\\
& = X\cap(A^{c}\cup B^{c})\\\\
& = X\cap(A\cap B)^{c}\\\\
& = X\backslash(A\cap B)
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The property you are asked to prove is a DeMorgan identity; it can help to visualize it by drawing a Venn diagram.

The step you have wrong is the following:

"Consequently, $x \in X $ and $x \notin (A∩B)$, and therefore, $x \notin A$ and $x \notin B$."

If an element is not in the intersection of two sets, it is not in *at least one* of two sets.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P$ be $x\in X.$ Let $Q$ be $x\in A$. Let $R$ be $x\in B.$ Observe that $$ x\in (X\setminus A)\cup (X\setminus B)\iff [ (x\in (X\setminus A)\lor (x\in X\setminus B)]\iff [(P\land \neg Q)\lor (P\land \neg R)] .$$ Therefore for any $x$ we have $$x\in X\setminus (A\cap B)\iff$$ $$\iff [x\in X\land \neg (x\in A\land x\in B)]\iff$$ $$\iff [P \land \neg (Q\land R)]\iff$$ $$ \iff [P\land (\,(\neg Q)\lor (\neg R)\,)]\iff$$ $$\iff  [(P\land \neg Q)\lor (P\land \neg R)]\iff $$ $$\iff x\in (X\setminus A)\cup (X\setminus B).$$

Or we can say that any $x\in X$ belongs to  $X\setminus (A\cap B)$ iff $x$ does not belong to $A$ (and hence belongs to $X\setminus A$) OR $x$ does not belong to $B$ (and hence belongs to $X$ \ $B$).